# Set cookie for current directory and its subdirectories only

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following directories:

**Company > Model > Year**

I want cookies to be only set in the *Model* folder, not available to the *Company* directory but available in the *year* dir. The cookies I set in *Model* or *year* should be available to each other but the *parent* dir (Company) should not be able to see those cookies.

Its like: **sub.domain.xyz/app/company/model/year/index.php**

Cookie: `setcookie('year', $year, time() + (86400), "/");`

I do know that "/" will set the cookie for the whole domain.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting to "/Company/Model". It's explained here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html under the domain and path section.